# In Android EditText, how to remove suggestions bar from soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have an android app with an EditText field in one of my layouts.  I have set `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` attribute for my EditText.  The text field no longer displays suggestions. However, the suggestions bar is still at the top of the soft keyboard and right now seems to only serve the purpose of displaying the voice input microphone icon.  I don't want/care about voice input for this field either, and would like to remove the suggestions bar from this soft keyboard.  Is there a way to do that, possibly with another inputType flag?

Comment: Usually the voice input icon is at the bottom of the keyboard right next to the space-bar. Do you use a Third-Party keyboard? They're known for ignoring "things"

Comment: No this is Nexus 5 w/ kit kat 4.4 stock OS stock keyboard

Comment: This did not solve removing the Suggestions Bar completely.

Answer (score 14):

I've found a solution that works for me. 
Looking at the logcat while pressing the search bar in Google Now launcher shows the following:

```
07-03 19:50:07.760    1304-1304/? W/LatinIME﹕ Deprecated private IME option specified: nm
07-03 19:50:07.760    1304-1304/? W/LatinIME﹕ Use com.google.android.inputmethod.latin.noMicrophoneKey instead
```

So, what I did was adding this line in the EditText xml:

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
```

"nm" is taken from the source code of LatinIME:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java#93

```
public static final String IME_OPTION_NO_MICROPHONE_COMPAT = "nm";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works and helps a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: Woah, great observation there, but I stil see the suggestions bar. The microphone icon is gone though.

Comment: how to enable suggestion bar in android? is there any key to enable?

Answer (score 4):

The combination of XML attributes that removed both the Suggestions and the Suggestions Bar while retaining multi-line text was the following:

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions | textMultiLine"
```

or

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
android:inputType="textFilter | textMultiLine"
```

Comment: The one downside I noticed of implementing this is that now the EditText field which had a maxLines of 3 lines set is kept to just one line which is not ideal.

I'm working on a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" to editext